# Need help identifying Japanese font used in logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

I looking to make a custom/higher quality version of the logo for Hanagumi Taisen Columns. I've tried many different japanese font sites and font identification sites such as likefont.com but so far I haven't had any luck finding this specific font. Help identifying this font would be really appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried manipulating the text before uploading to likefont.com? You may have to remove all the background and outlines, and de-skew the text, darken it, and separate the two characters to get a good result

Comment: We've had a lot of questions on Japanese fonts recently. Unfortunately, it's always the same answer: nobody here seems to know much about them and these questions never get good answers. Maybe try a Japanese graphic design forum?